# jquery/javascript concat question

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I want to create a jQuery statement that looks like this:

```
$('.total_999').html("something");
```

However, `999` comes from variable called `storeNo`.

How can I construct this statement dynamically?

Comment: Can you come up with a better selector for getting total_999? can you show some html with the total_999 element?

Answer (score 7):

$('.total_'+storeNo).html("something");

Comment: that would resolve to :

$('.total_'+storeNo).html("something");

Comment: No it would not, @roger rover. You say that the variable named "storeNo" contains 999. You're not making the mistake of trying to do this in an "eval()" are you?  Don't do that.

Comment: @Ender Hey thanks, Pointy to. And Roger Rover why is it not working? Post more code this should work.

Answer (score 1):

total_999 in your example is a class. Since it appears to be unique (or likely so), then it should probably be the id, and use a more generic class.

for example:

```
<div id="total_999" class="total">...</div>
```

then you can use the id, or the class to refer to the element

```
$('#total_'+storeNo); //get the element
```

or

```
$('.total'); //get all of the totals
```

A more complete example might be:

```
function setTotal(storeNo, total) {
  $('#total_'+storeNo).html(total);
}

setTotal(999,'$1,276');
```

Comment: right. It is id, but this
...$('#total'+store_number);  does not resolve to #totall999

Comment: roger, `store_number=999;$('#total_'+store_number);` resolves to the element with id "total_999"

Comment: changed the variable name to match the one you used in the question